# Form field input empty than do not update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that updates a user's info.  How can I tell the form to NOT update certain fields when left blank?

```
if(trim($email) == '') { /* don't update */ }
```

Comment: you have to go the other way and tell your php script to only update fields that are NOT blank.

Comment: Is the idea here to update the fields of a database record, but if the user has left a field blank to leave whatever value is already in the database rather than wiping it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update one or more fields ignoring the empty fields into mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522096/how-to-update-one-or-more-fields-ignoring-the-empty-fields-into-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2):

This is better:

```
if ( empty( trim( $email ) ) )
{
    // do not update
}
else
{
    // update
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(trim($email) == '') {}else{ YOUR UPDATE SCRIPT HERE }
```

Comment: ^ this checks to see if email is '' or nothing, if so then it does {} which = nothing, if it is not '' or nothing then it goes on to do the update script.