# Is there an easy way to skip updating a field to an empty value in a database?

Tags: php

This starts when a user fills out a form with optional inputs. The values are passed by AJAX to another PHP page to insert into a database. If a particular input is empty, I don't want to update the data stored in the database. Is there a way to check, besides writing lots of `if` statements, to see if an input value is empty? If it is empty, how can I write the statement so MySQL won't update the corresponding field in the database?

```
if(isset($_POST['f_name']) && isset($_POST['m_name']) && isset($_POST['l_name']) && isset($_POST['alt_name'])){
    $fname = $_POST['f_name'];
    $mname = $_POST['m_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['l_name'];
    $altname = $_POST['alt_name'];
```

If some of the $_POST entries are empty, then they shouldn't be put into the database. I'm saying this because if there's already an existing value in the database, I don't want to overwrite the value with an empty one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form field input empty than do not update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577678/form-field-input-empty-than-do-not-update), [how to update one or more fields ignoring the empty fields into mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522096/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you also don't allow people to enter just a `blank space` / `&bnsp;`

```
<?php
$empty = FALSE;

foreach ($_POST as $key)
{
    if (!isset($key) || strlen(trim($key)) != 0)
    {
      $empty = TRUE;
    }
}

if (!$empty)
{
    $fname = $_POST['f_name'];
    $mname = $_POST['m_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['l_name'];
    $altname = $_POST['alt_name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: if(!empty) is for all variables? I want to be able to insert all variables that are not having a space. Would I put the query update inside the if(!empty) also?

Comment: so I can just put `UPDATE user SET fname = '$fname', mname = '$mname', lname = '$lname', altname = '$altname'`; and each of those set parameters would only work if it doesn't have an empty input?

Comment: Yes.. But don't forget to validate the input first!!

Comment: @EnricoPallazzo : hey, I've same issue, I'm using CodeIgniter. Will help me how to use this code in CodeIgniter Model, I'm useing Stored Procedure to store/ update data.

Answer (score 1):

well...you could use foreach to check all the values.

```
$empty = FALSE;
   foreach ($_POST as $key) {
    if (!isset($key)) {
      $empty = TRUE;
       break;
   }
}

if (!$empty) {
$fname = $_POST['f_name'];
    $mname = $_POST['m_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['l_name'];
    $altname = $_POST['alt_name'];
}
```

Comment: In this case you also allow people just an `space` / `&nbsp;`. And, you are missing a `)` on the 3rd line.

Comment: true,thanks for pointing that out. if ($key == '') would probably fix that though. Unless i'm missing something again

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo: In the case of a space, the value isn't empty and in the context of the question, shouldn't be filtered.

Comment: @adlawson It's a common mistake I see everywhere. I doubt there's anyone who has a `<space>` as their first, middle or last name.

Comment: @Darvex `if (!isset(trim($key)))` is a bit useless. If you use `trim()` you need to use it like this: `strlen(trim($key)) != 0`. First you remove the space and if the length of the remaining string is equal to `0` it will return as false.

Comment: ehhh, i'll just leave it like it was...guess it's lack of sleep.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use shorthand if statments (also known as the ternary operator) to do something like this. You might be able to write your SQL query something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET f_name = ".(!empty($fname) ? "'$fname'" : 'f_name').", m_name = ".(!empty($mname) ? "'$mname'" : 'm_name').", ";
//etc.. etc..
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Not to mention that queries (or anything, really) with `f_name = f_name` is pretty nasty.

Comment: Values shouldn't be interpolated directly into statements. Instead, build the statement with positional parameters and use a prepared statement.

Comment: @SLaks Obviously I would deal with that before the line posted above. My posted solution is just a small snippet sample to demonstrate logic. @ adlawson In this context it's perfectly fine, I'm using it to simply set a field's value equal to itself in the event that the user provided value is empty.